# Function that returns dynamically allocated string works once, then returns garbage values on subsequent calls (after free has been called)

Tags: c

All in title really. I have included screen shots to see my code as well as output. Basically I call a function that returns a dynamically allocated string (char*), print it in main, and it looks perfect. I then free the variable, and upon calling the function again I get a garbage output, which seems like a memory error but I have no idea where it could come from.
Appreciate any help, been stuck for a couple hours.
Thanks!

[image: function]
[image: main]
[image: output]

Sorry if these links are annoying, my first time posting

Comment: Please add the code as part of the question and not as a capture.

Comment: Please edit your code into your question as a text [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're building your results into uninitialized string arrays:

```
char result[200];
```

...

```
strcat(result, ...);
```

Uninitialized variables may have any content in them. You can add a null character as a first character right after declaring the variable:

```
char result[200];
result[0] = '\0';
```

this way the first character will be a string terminator and string functions will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks so much that was exactly it. Guess I still don't have all the little things down that you need to code in c properly... Also thanks for responding even with images ill be sure to post code in my next post.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call the free(); function you deallocate the memory you had previously allocated to store a string so when you run your code it throws out garbage values since there is no string to print (because there is no memory to store that string in). A possible solution may be to make sure your function allocates enough memory for string everytime you call it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the C programming language does not initializes any new variable by default, so a good practice is to always initialize everything:

```
117 char argcs[10] = { 0 };
118 char arguments[200] = { 0 };
119 char result[200] = { 0 };
120 char *result2 = NULL;
```

Instead of using malloc you could use calloc and also initialize the newly allocated memory:

```
154 result2 = calloc(sizeof(result));
```

Memory usage here is small so I made changes that increases the performance.
If you are going to make use of big amounts of memory it might not be always desirable to initialize everything because of the performance hit, but in this scenario is ok to go ahead and set everything to 0.

There are some concerning issues here with how you handle your strings using strcat without checking to avoid for overflows if the input is larger than 200. That is a pretty unsafe use of your strings there.

However, the most concerning problem is when you return the address of your malloc placed in a local variable. Since you are storing a pointer address in a local variable, once you leave the function this local storage is released and another memory allocation could overwrite this previously defined location creating effectively a memory leak and potentially returning garbage on the execution or in a very unlucky scenario a segmentation fault and a core dump.